# Terminal Server cannot connect from specific computer

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We have a win2k3 Terminal server. I have just set up a new user and granted them access. I have a mac running Remote desktop, and I can access it just fine using that client.

When I go to the users computer and try to connect, I'm getting the error message "Must add to the Remote Desktop Users group" etc.

What could possibly be the issue? Are there restrictions in Terminal Server that limit which computer clients can connect from?

I've also noticed that Administrators can log in from that users computer, but no normal user accounts (which work fine from any other computer on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each unique user needs to be a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group on the Terminal Server. In an AD domain this is usually accomplished by adding each user to a domain group and then adding that group to the local Remote Desktop Users group.